# PHP - Successful INSERT but no database entry

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to submit values from a form into my database. The PHP is returning query successful but there is no database entry. I have tried printing the submitted query and copying it into MySQL Workbench and the query runs and inserts the data as expected.

HTML:

```
<form action="queries/insertData.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <select id="name" name="name">
  <?php 
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<option value=". $row['name'] .">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
    }
  ?>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Step Number:<br>
  <input type="text" id="stepCount" name="stepCountAmount" value="">
  <br><br>
  Date:<br>
  <input type="date" id="stepCountDate" name="date" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

insertData.php

```
<?php
  require '../database.php';
  $query = "INSERT INTO stepcount (userID, stepNumber, countDate)
  VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["stepCountAmount"]."','".$_POST["date"]."')";
    if($query) {
      echo "Query was successful ";
      echo $query;
    }
    else {
      echo "Query Unsuccessful";
    }
  mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The `echo`'d out query:

```
 INSERT INTO stepcount (userID, stepNumber, countDate) VALUES ('Three','100','2018-10-01')
```

Comment: `if($query) {` returns `true` if `$query` is set (which it is). It does not check if the query was successful. You don't run that query anywhere. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: also welcome to SQL Injection

Comment: I don't see where is insert query execution

Comment: You are not running the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `mysqli_query`

insertData.php

```
<?php
 require '../database.php';
  $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO stepcount (userID, stepNumber, countDate)
  VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["stepCountAmount"]."','".$_POST["date"]."')");

if($query) {
  echo "Query was successful ";
  echo $query;
}
else {
  echo "Query Unsuccessful";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Heads up, shouldn't `$conn` be the first argument?

Comment: Shouldn't `$conn` be `$link`?

Comment: @kerbholz true. Edited

Comment: @HarveyFletcher . Thanks for pointing out. my mistake . Edited

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to actually execute the query, you are just checking the existence of the query string

Answer (score 0):

You're not running the query, you'll need to use the line:

```
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

and this will run the query on your `$link` connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query using below command and make sure you have a valid database connection.

```
$conn->query($query)
```